# onCreate is called as expected. But tables are not created

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I've got this problem which is really annoying me. I override the onCreate method of my class extending SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onCreate(db);
    final String createAccTableCmd = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            ACCOUNT_KEY_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, " +
            ACCOUNT_KEY_SELECTED + " INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, " + //THIS IS IN MILLISECONDS
            "CHECK (" + ACCOUNT_KEY_SELECTED + " = 0 OR " + ACCOUNT_KEY_SELECTED + " = 1) ON CONFLICT IGNORE" +
            " ) ");
    final String oneAndOnlyOneSelectedAccInsertTriggerCmd = "CREATE TRIGGER " + ONE_AND_ONLY_ONE_SELECTED_TRIGGER_INSERT_NAME + " " +
            "AFTER INSERT ON " + ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME + " " +
            "FOR EACH ROW " +
            "BEGIN " +
            "DELETE FROM " + ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + " = NEW." + ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + "; " +
            "END";
    final String oneAndOnlyOneSelectedUpdateTriggerCmd = "CREATE TRIGGER " + ONE_AND_ONLY_ONE_SELECTED_TRIGGER_UPDATE_NAME + " " +
            "AFTER UPDATE ON " + ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME + " " +
            "FOR EACH ROW " +
            "WHEN (SELECT(SUM(" + ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + ")) <> 1) " +
            "BEGIN " +
            "UPDATE " + ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + ACCOUNT_KEY_SELECTED + " = 0; " +
            "UPDATE " + ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + ACCOUNT_KEY_SELECTED + " = 1 WHERE " + ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + " = NEW." + ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + "; " +
            "END";
    synchronized (DB_LOCK) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.execSQL(createAccTableCmd);
        db.execSQL(oneAndOnlyOneSelectedAccInsertTriggerCmd);
        db.execSQL(oneAndOnlyOneSelectedUpdateTriggerCmd);
        addTableName(ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ACCOUNT_KEY_ID, 0);
        cv.put(ACCOUNT_KEY_NAME, "name");
        cv.put(ACCOUNT_KEY_SELECTED, 0);
        Log.d("debug", "-1 if error on insert: " + db.insert(ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME, "", cv));
        Log.d("debug", "Size: " + db.query(ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + " ASC").getCount());
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        LBackupAgent.requestBackup(mContext);
    }
    Log.d("debug", "Size after ending the transaction: " + db.query(ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + " ASC").getCount());
}
```

One would expect the output of this to be:

- -1 if error on insert: 0
- Size: 0 /* or 1, if the select takes into account the data not committed of the current transaction, I'm not sure about this */
- Size after ending the transaction: 1

When the actual output happens to be:

- -1 if error on insert: 0
- Size: 0
- Size after ending the transaction: 0

How can it be that the insertion is successful but the selection returns 0 rows? 
I've checked with a shell that the table does exist, but effectively it is empty, which could be explained by the fact that the tables do not seem to be really existing until onCreate() finishes, justifying as well the 0 returned by the insertion command. Should I guess that this some kind of design constraint to make sure that onCreate does only include CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER and such type of statements? What if I consider that my schema definition needs an insertion (as is the case)?

Comment: `onCreate()` already runs in a transaction, and sqlite does not support nested transactions. Android sqlite atttempts to provide some support for nested transactions but the support is incomplete: The actual commit/rollback is only performed when the outermost transaction completes. Don't use transactions in `onCreate()`. Though this doesn't really explain your output.

Comment: It doesn't explain the output, but it's good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting some dummy values instead of below:

```
ContentValues defaultAcc = mapAccountToStorable(defaultAccDataModel = new AccountListRecyclerAdapter.AccountDataModel(
                        LBudgetUtils.getInt(mContext, "default_account_id"),
                        LBudgetUtils
                                .getString(mContext, "default_account_name"),
                        mContext.getResources().getBoolean(
                                R.bool.default_account_selected)));
```

Instead of sending nullColumnHack as null send it as "". It will make sure that a row will be created in table even if values are null.

```
db.insert(ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME, "", defaultAcc)
```

Try below:

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL(createAccTableCmd);
    db.execSQL(oneAndOnlyOneSelectedAccInsertTriggerCmd);
    db.execSQL(oneAndOnlyOneSelectedUpdateTriggerCmd);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    db.beginTransaction();
    addTableName(ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME);
    AccountListRecyclerAdapter.AccountDataModel defaultAccDataModel;
    ContentValues defaultAcc = mapAccountToStorable(defaultAccDataModel = new AccountListRecyclerAdapter.AccountDataModel(LBudgetUtils.getInt(mContext, "default_account_id"), LBudgetUtils.getString(mContext, "default_account_name"), mContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.default_account_selected)));
    Log.d("debug", "-1 if error on insert: " + db.insert(ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME, null, defaultAcc));
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();


    Log.d("debug", "Size: " + db.query(ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ACCOUNT_KEY_ID + " ASC").getCount());
```

Comment: Using the "" column hack and a hard-coded ContentValues object still  results in the same outcome.

Comment: I think when logs are printed, transaction is not completed. Try fetching/logging data once transaction is done.  Updated the answer

Comment: There's another log command outside the endtransaction, which by the way does not really matter (see comment by @laalto). And anyway, checking through shell (once that the onCreate has for sure finished) does show that the table is empty as well.

Comment: I tried same and works for me.. Can you try removing Triggers. I suspect problem is due to that.

Comment: Confirmed. The first trigger was lacking the WHEN condition.